# Namespace not visible within a proect. ( The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace )

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf project, with files BelekeService.cs, IBelekeService.cs and  folder DAL

[image]

So, in my `Service.cs` I can write `using Beleke.App_Code.DAL;` and everything compiles, but if I write the same code in IBelekeService.cs I get a compilation error - `The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace  (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

For some reason, in my object browser, there are two different projects:

[image]

Object Browser:
[image]

Comment: can you check if the object browser is referring to two different assemblies? Looks like the one you are using is outdated

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat How can I do that?

Comment: bottom of the right hand pane of object explorer shows the Path of the assembly

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat I added a screenshot. Turns out that I can not add a  `using` directive to any local namespace in neither `Service.cs` nor in `IService.cs`

Comment: for some weird reason you have two projects listed which is why you have this problem. What happens when you right clock on a project in object browser and click goto declaration, do they both point to the same project?

Comment: Solved it by changing BuildAction to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was solved when I changed  `BuildAction` of all items generated via Entity Data Model to `compile`